# GFCI tripping frequently

Tags: electrical, gfci

Can a refrigerator be connected to one of the load receptacles from a GFCI. Of late, GFCI is tripping very frequently. What is the solution for this. Would replacing the GFCI with a new one resolve this issue. My GFCI is pretty old like 20 years.

Comment: Do you have any way to measure the differential current (such as a sensitive clampmeter around hot and neutral)?

Comment: Yes, there is such a thing as old GFCIs tripping.  There is also such a thing as appliances having ground faults!   My opinion is that a refrigerator should not be on a GFCI for obvious reasons, but unfortunately the Electrical Code does not agree with that opinion.  If Code compels you to have a fridge on a GFCI, at least make it a dedicated circuit so only the fridge (or a bad GFCI) can cause a trip.

Comment: What else is on the GFCI circuit?

Comment: My state exempts fridges from gfci requirements. GFCI'S do fail but from what I see the newer ones are even more sensitive than older ones. In the code handbook it states that newer appliances have less issues ( so just spend more on a new fridge or ruin all your food and risk eating spoiled food), my words but this is one are I strongly disagree with code and am glad my state still exempts fridges and freezers from gfci requirements. So check your local code to verify if they are required.

Answer (score 1):

If your refrigerator is on a dedicated circuit, then a GFCI is not required.

GFCI protection is also not required for receptacles that are not readily accessible [whatever that means].

When I wired my laundry room which included provisions for a refrigerator, I mounted the receptacle up high (so I could reach it above the refrig, which in located in a little alcove), and put it on it's own dedicated circuit.

Note, I was doing this work with a licensed master electrician, had all the necessary permits, and passed electrical & final inspections.

Answer (score 0):

If a not-so-old GFCI is tripping then you could have something hot touching the metal case inside the fridge. I have had more-than-a-tingle from fridges that were not on GFCI's.  At these voltages you really want to know for sure.

If it is a really old GFCI then that would be a secondary thing to look at.

Either way, it might be wise to seek professional assistance.

Comment: Old compressors can exhibit internal insulation breakdown and produce leakage as a result ('tis why commercial HVAC guys megger 'em)

Comment: Not so much old systems but systems that have gone acidic, moisture in the oil turned to acid that eats the varnish off the motor windings and then there can/ will be ground faults, however I have found that to rarely be the case with GFCI's tripping, many times if someone wants the GFCI on the fridge I will change it out and most of the times this fixes the problem. Bad start run caps and crank case heaters on the compressor that have failed have been the cause more often than a burn out caused by acidic oil FWIW.